# Parsing argument list specifying a player to be added

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I want to start off by saying sorry, I wasn't able to search for this problem as I couldn't exactly describe it myself.

I have a series of if-statements to account for each scenario. As you can see in the mammoth block of code below, I want arguments to come in any order. **How, if possible, can I shorten this?**

```
if(args[1].startsWith("u:") && args[2].startsWith("r:") && args[3].startsWith("l:")){ // u / r / l
    Player p = player.getServer().getPlayer(args[1].split(":")[1]);
    String r = args[2].split(":")[1];
    String l = args[3].split(":")[1];
    Config.addPlayer(p, r, l, player);
    return true;
}else if(args[1].startsWith("r:") && args[2].startsWith("l:") && args[3].startsWith("u:")){ // r / l / u
    Player p = player.getServer().getPlayer(args[3].split(":")[1]);
    String r = args[1].split(":")[1];
    String l = args[2].split(":")[1];
    Config.addPlayer(p, r, l, player);
    return true;
}else if(args[1].startsWith("l:") && args[2].startsWith("u:") && args[3].startsWith("r:")){ // l / u / r
    Player p = player.getServer().getPlayer(args[2].split(":")[1]);
    String r = args[3].split(":")[1];
    String l = args[1].split(":")[1];
    Config.addPlayer(p, r, l, player);
    return true;
}else if(args[1].startsWith("u") && args[2].startsWith("l:") && args[3].startsWith("r:")){ // u / l / r
    Player p = player.getServer().getPlayer(args[1].split(":")[1]);
    String r = args[3].split(":")[1];
    String l = args[2].split(":")[1];
    Config.addPlayer(p, r, l, player);
    return true;
}else if(args[1].startsWith("l:") && args[2].startsWith("r:") && args[3].startsWith("u:")){ // l / r / u
    Player p = player.getServer().getPlayer(args[2].split(":")[1]);
    String r = args[2].split(":")[1];
    String l = args[1].split(":")[1];
    Config.addPlayer(p, r, l, player);
    return true;
}else if(args[1].startsWith("r:") && args[2].startsWith("u:") && args[3].startsWith("l:")){ // r / u / l
    Player p = player.getServer().getPlayer(args[2].split(":")[1]);
    String r = args[1].split(":")[1];
    String l = args[3].split(":")[1];
    Config.addPlayer(p, r, l, player);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: If your code works and you are looking for a way to improve it then you should post this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks! I was unaware such site existed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Player p = null;
String r = null;
String l = null;

for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  String[] components = args[i].split(":");
  switch(components[0]) {
    case "u":
      p = player.getServer().getPlayer(components[1]);
      break;
    case "r":
      r = components[1];
      break;
    case "l":
      l = components[1];
  }
}

if (p != null && r != null && l != null) {
  Config.addPlayer(p, r, l, player);
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could copy the array with [`Arrays.copyOfRange(T[], int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T[],%20int,%20int%29) and then sort it with [`Arrays.sort(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object[]%29). Something like,

```
String[] tmp = Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 1, args.length);
Arrays.sort(tmp);
if(tmp[0].startsWith("l:") && tmp[1].startsWith("r:")
        && tmp[2].startsWith("u:"))
{   /* l / r / u */
    Player p = player.getServer().getPlayer(tmp[2].split(":")[1]);
    String r = tmp[1].split(":")[1];
    String l = tmp[0].split(":")[1];
    Config.addPlayer(p, r, l, player);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### What you are looking for is called `Chain of Responsibility` pattern:

Since you don't show enough context of what this is actually supposed to be doing, I just named the classes and methods strawman names, use more contextual names.

And you will have to modify what is in the `isValid()` method maybe, but this is the general way to handle exploding `if/elseif/else` statements.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final List<Scenario> scenarios = new ArrayList<>();
    scenarios.add(new Scenario("u:", "r:", "l:"));
    scenarios.add(new Scenario("r:", "L:", "u:"));
    scenarios.add(new Scenario("l:", "u:", "r:"));

    for (final Scenario f : scenarios)
    {
        if (f.isValid(args)) { break; }
    }
}

public static class Scenario
{
    private final String arg1prefix;
    private final String arg2prefix;
    private final String arg3prefix;

    public Scenario(@Nonnull final String arg1prefix, @Nonnull final String arg2prefix, final String arg3prefix)
    {
        this.arg1prefix = arg1prefix;
        this.arg2prefix = arg2prefix;
        this.arg3prefix = arg3prefix;
    }

    public boolean isValid(@Nonnull final String... args)
    {
        if (args[1].startsWith(this.arg1prefix) && args[2].startsWith(this.arg2prefix) && args[3].startsWith(this.arg3prefix))
        {
            final Player p = player.getServer().getPlayer(args[1].split(":")[1]);
            final String r = args[2].split(":")[1];
            final String l = args[3].split(":")[1];
            Config.addPlayer(p, r, l, player);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```